# undo-tree doesn't auto load history

Tags: emacs, undo

I was trying to make persistent undo history work in emacs.

I have `(setq undo-tree-auto-save history t)`. The history is indeed saved when I save file. But when I open file, the undo history is not loaded until I use undo.

So if I open a file and make some changes, then run `M-x undo-tree-visualize`, the previous undo tree is gone, only the recent changes are there. But if I run `M-x undo-tree-visualize` first, then I can see the old undo tree. Or if I just use undo before making any changes, the old undo history is loaded and the undo works as expected.

**Edit:** My configuration looks like this: https://gitlab.com/snippets/22693

**Edit2:** This problem still happens with the most minimal configure file:

```
;;; init.el --- user init file      -*- no-byte-compile: t -*-
(load-file "~/.emacs.d/undo-tree.el")
(global-undo-tree-mode 1)
(setq undo-tree-auto-save-history t)
```

Comment: Have you got `(global-undo-tree-mode 1)`. Please show us your configuration.

Comment: @djangoliv My configuration: https://gitlab.com/snippets/22693

Answer (score 1):

How come no one has ever noticed this? There's a bug in undo-tree.

The function undo-list-transfer-to-tree failed to append 'undo-tree-canary to buffer-undo-list, which cause it to discard the content of buffer-undo-tree.

I'm still looking into it to see if I can find a solution. Simply append 'undo-tree-canary to buffer-undo-list causing it to discard to content in buffer-undo-list instead

**Edit:** The solution is indeed to put canary at the end of buffer-undo-list

```
  (when (not (eq (last buffer-undo-list) 'undo-tree-canary))
    (setq buffer-undo-list (append buffer-undo-list '(nil undo-tree-canary))))
```

Comment: This answer makes no sense, doesn't solve your problem, and is dangerous. There's definitely no bug here in `undo-list-transfer-to-tree`. Blithely appending the canary onto the end of `buffer-undo-list` without having a clue what you're doing is not going to help you.

Comment: The canary is used to detect if Emacs has discarded undo history before undo-tree got a chance to see it. If the canary's gone, it means `buffer-undo-list` exceeded one of `undo-[outer-|strong-]limit` and some history has been discarded. In this case, `buffer-undo-tree` needs to be discarded and rebuilt from the contents of `buffer-undo-list`. Which is exactly what `undo-list-transfer-to-tree` does in this case. Anyway, this has nothing to do with loading saved history from file.

Answer (score 1):

When `undo-tree-auto-save-history` is enabled, undo history is loaded from file by the `undo-tree-load-history-hook` function, which gets added to `find-file-hook`. So undo history will be loaded automatically when you open a file with `undo-tree-mode` enabled.

@djangoliv is right: this will only work if `global-undo-tree-mode` is enabled, because `undo-tree-mode` needs to be enabled before `find-file-hook` is called. Perhaps the `undo-tree-mode` minor-mode function ought to attempt to load history if it detects the buffer hasn't been modified since the last undo history save. But at the moment, it doesn't.

However, your config does enable `global-undo-tree-mode`, so this can't be the issue.

History loading works just fine for me with `global-undo-tree-mode` enabled. So unless you give a complete MWE that reproduces your problem -- i.e. step-by-step instructions starting from "emacs -Q" and including Emacs and undo-tree version numbers -- you're unlikely to get much more help here. (Also, note that stackexchange is not a bug tracker. Bug reports should be sent by email to the address listed at the top of the package.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tinkered with the order you are loading your plugins as well as files you open automatically via init.el or .emacs? That did the trick for me. Evil requires Undo-Tree. So everything having to do with undo-tree should fire before you load Evil. Especially if you use ":e" instead of "find-file" for loading files. A least on my system that solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to chime in that I experience a similar thing.

if I `emacs file-x` from the terminal, earlier undo tree history for `file-x` is not is not available to me before I `undo-tree-load-history`. However, when I open emacs and *then* `:edit file-x`, the history is loaded just fine.

I'm using `spacemacs 0.105.19`, with `emacs-24.5.1`.

My `.spacemacs` is https://pastebin.com/VNWtB0F1

Comment: In the former case, the file is presumably being visited before `undo-tree` has been loaded.

Comment: That sounds very plausible. I don't know emacs-lisp and so don't know how to properly test it, debug it or rectify the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Reason for this behavior is that when you start up emacs and open up file in buffer even with `undo-tree-auto-save-history` enabled so that `undo-tree-load-history` is called as it should be, `buffer-undo-list` is initially set to `nil`. If you make an edit before invoking any functionality of undo-tree, `buffer-undo-list` will have value that doesn't end with an `undo-tree-canary`.

When `undo-list-transfer-to-tree` sees `buffer-undo-list` not ending with `undo-tree-canary`, it will discard current `buffer-undo-tree` and construct new one with the value of `buffer-undo-list` which only have undo history of your initial edit. Consequently, `buffer-undo-tree` previously built by `undo-tree-load-history` is deleted, and you are left with fresh, minimal `buffer-undo-tree` only with single undo history.

So what I did to prevent this from happening was to initialize `buffer-undo-list` with `undo-tree-canary` by advising `undo-tree-load-history-hook` which should call `undo-tree-load-history` with `undo-tree-auto-save-history` set to `t`, and it is also called for opening file as part of `find-file-hook`.

That is, I added this line of code to my init file:

```
(advice-add 'undo-tree-load-history-hook :after (lambda () (setq buffer-undo-list '(nil undo-tree-canary))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `(global-undo-tree-mode)` in the `:init` will auto load history if you're using `use-package`

Example:

```lisp
(use-package undo-tree
  :init
  (global-undo-tree-mode)
  :custom
  (undo-tree-auto-save-history t)
  (undo-tree-history-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.config/emacs/undo-tree-history")))
  (undo-tree-visualizer-diff t)
  (undo-tree-visualizer-timestamps t))
```